# What country of residence should I put in the Incoming Passenger Card if I have moved countries after my Australian visa was granted?

Tags: visas, australia

So basically Im a student in Singapore for 2 years and by the time im applying for my Australian student visa im using singapore as my country of residence as I studied there before.

I got my student visa granted with the information stating that singapore is my country of residence

However I have done my studies in singapore and right now im staying in my country which is Indonesia
and singapore is not longer my country of residence

So my question is which country of residence should I fill in the Incoming passenger card once I arrived In Australia? Will it cause a confusion for the officer ?

Help me pls coz its going to be my first time studying in Australia and im so nervous , thanks

Answer (score 3):

**It doesn't matter**, but I would recommend writing Indonesia, because it's currently correct.  If you're asked (which is unlikely), you can simply state the truth: your studies in Singapore are finished and you're now moving from Indonesia to Australia to study more.

More generally, you've completed the "hard part" of getting your student visa already.  You're not going to be examined in detail on entering Australia, unless there is serious reason to believe you're not actually a student.

Comment: And that’s actually a good impression.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , its help me to get chill for a bit